# Rock Paper Scissors looping method in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

So basically I am designing a Rock-Paper-Scissors game.

I have three methods(Move) to choose from depending on their win rate. Let's call it: `methodA()`, `methodB()`, `methodC()`.

Now I need to perform a check every 30 rounds to check the win rate.

I have a piece of code like this:

```
Move nextMove(){ //Move is a enum including Rock,Paper,Scissors
    Move makeMove;
    vector<float> checkWinRate = {winRateA,winRateB,winRateC};
    //saving my win rates into a vector and sort it
    std::sort(checkWinRate.begin(),checkWinRate.end()); 
    if (checkWinRate.back() == winRateA)
        makeMove = methodA();
    else if (checkWinRate.back() == winRateB)
        makeMove = methodB();
    else
        makeMove = methodC();
    //choose methods according to win rates
    return makeMove;
}
```

What I'm doing now is I'm letting it check every time I call this function. 
However, my ultimate goal is to let it check every 30 rounds and run the same method for the next 30 rounds and check again. It sounds easy but I just can't think of anyway to do it.

Any idea what I should do here? Please Help.

Comment: Create a static integer in your Method and increment it in After each method call also include an if Statement which Checks if the integer is Thirty if it is The Code in the if Statement will run Then set the integer back to Zero

Comment: If checking the WinRate to make a move is critical, you need to do it for every round, no? If you run the same method for 30 rounds, without checking the rate, you'd be making the same move each time.

Comment: Each of my methods are implemented with different learning formulas, they will make moves depending on what they have learned from their opponent's move. I need to see how each method is doing in a period of time that's why I need to check it every 30 rounds. Can you write a short code in the answers about the static integer increment? I thought about this but I can't get it work. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an integer, increment it by one on each round, when it reaches 29 (30 rounds) you do your check and make it zero again.
Your numOfRounds will be 29 at first, in order to be able to enter any if at the beginning.

```
Move nextMove(static int numOfRounds){
    //...
    if ((checkWinRate.back() == winRateA) && numOfRounds == 29)
        makeMove = methodA();
        numOfRounds = 0;
    //...
    else{
        /*You need to choose a method here, my question is, will it
        break your original logic? I would choose randomly.*/
        numOfRounds++;
    }
    return makeMove;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I'm trying to do but I thought it over and decided to just do checks each round. It made my life way easier, and thanks!

Comment: It seems better this way. Since my answer didn't solve your problem, I can't ask you to accept it, but it would be nice.